# PDO registration form error

Tags: php

I get this error: `Uncaught exception 'PDOException'` in my php code.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    require 'connect.php';

    if(isset($_POST['register'])){

        $username = !empty($_POST['username']) ? trim($_POST['username']) : null;
        $pass = !empty($_POST['password']) ? trim($_POST['password']) : null;

        //Construct the SQL statement and prepare it.
        $sql = "SELECT COUNT(username) AS num FROM user  WHERE username = :username";
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

        //Bind the provided username to our prepared statement.                   $stmt->bindValue(':username', $username);

        //Execute.
        $stmt->execute();

        //Fetch the row.
        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if($row['num'] > 0){
            die('That username already exists!');
        }

        //Prepare our INSERT statement.
        //Remember: We are inserting a new row into our users table.
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (:username, :password)";
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

        //Bind our variables.
        $stmt->bindValue(':username', $username);
        $stmt->bindValue(':password', $passwordHash);

        //Execute the statement and insert the new account.
        $result = $stmt->execute();

        //If the signup process is successful.
        if($result){
            //What you do here is up to you!
            echo 'Thank you for registering with our website.';
        }

    }

?>
```

Here is the full error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'user.user' doesn't exist' in C:\xampp\htdocs\simplereg\register.php:13 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\simplereg\register.php(13): PDO->prepare('SELECT COUNT(us...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\simplereg\register.php on line 13.
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: your code is not tidy, you should better show your code more beauty and tidy by using  Control + K

Comment: Tabbed code correctly, added some more commentary for clearer explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Here you say the table name is `user`

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(username) AS num FROM user  WHERE username = :username";
```

but here you say the table name is `users`

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (:username, :password)";
```

I would guess one of them is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests, `"Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'user.user' doesn't exist".` You are using wrong table name. Fix it.

From your code example, I guess the table name would be `users`.